# Printing Multiple pages in wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm, printing

I have a Scroll Viewer and inside that a text block with multiple pages contents.
How can I print everything within the Scroll Viewer.I'm Using WPF MVVM pattern.
Is text block is the right control for this?Or shall I go for any other WPF controls.?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: AFAIK there is no magic pagination bullet.  You have to do it all yourself.

Comment: Actually my Print Icommand from the ViewlModel gets the textBlocks contents.But I'm Getting the following error while printing PrintTicket provider failed to retrieve PrintCapabilities. Win32 error. Here is my Code to Print printDlg.PrintDocument(idpSource.DocumentPaginator, "Hello WPF Printing.");

Comment: Never seen that error.  Seems like your question and the problem you're having are two different things.

Comment: Sometimes will get Error like that..Plz Chk dis Link http://petterisbetter.com/michael/index.php/2008/09/29/printticket-provider-failed-to-retrieve-#more28

Comment: "This is essentially a driver problem, but inevitably there will be instances where your software runs on drivers you didn't know about or in environments where driver upgrades may not be possible." If your drivers suck, there isn't much you can do.  Upgrade your printer drivers, or upgrade your printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is exactly the problem,But something related to Printer.

From Control Panel->Printers & Fax

1.Right Click the Printer and take Printer preferences

2.Change the Source property to 'Manual Feed'& Apply.(Initially it was'AutoSelect')

3.Still got some error.

4.Again me changed the Source property back to 'Auto Select'& Apply.

5.Changed the Quick set Property to 'Defaults'& Apply

5.Now its Working Fine

Answer (score 0):

[DocumentViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748388.aspx) ir a better control for paginated [printing](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2009/07/09/wpf-printing-part-4-ndash-print-preview.aspx)